# Rails JavaScript include TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.style')

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, onload, reveal.js

I've downloaded an external script and placed it in my vendor/assets/javascripts, then included it in application.js (the reveal script)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require reveal
//= require mustache
//= require_tree .
```

The [script](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) apparently doesn't wait for DOM load because I the above error in my console. How can I make sure that the body has loaded before setting the JS loose?

**EDIT**
Reveal is initialized in its own file, reveal_init.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  Reveal.initialize
    controls: true,
    progress: false,
    history: true,
    loop: false,
    mouseWheel: true,

    # Apply a 3D roll to links on hover
    rollingLinks: true,
    theme: 'default', 
    transition: 'page' # default/cube/page/concave/linear(2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Reveal.initialize({
    opt1: "value",
    opt2: "value"
  });
});
```

Or, when using CoffeeScript:

```
$ -> 
  Reveal.initialize
    opt1: "value"
    opt2: "value"
```

If you still get an error that an object is not present yet, you might want to try out the [$(window).load()](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) event, which fires even later than the `ready()` event.

If that still doesn't work, and you are sure the element is there and should be working, try adding a delay in loading the script, using `setTimeout`, or fire the script manually using the web developer tools in Chrome/Safari or Firebug in Firefox.

If that still doesn't work, you can now rule out the possibility of the script loading too soon, and you should start investigating other possibilities.

Comment: A more normal way to do is `$(function(){})`.

Comment: More like a more cryptic way. Not sure what the deal is with jQuery's obsessive overloading of the `$` function. Using `$(document).ready(...` is perfectly normal, and much clearer.

Comment: I edited the question. The initialize is in its own file that uses jQuery's ready function. Still getting the error

Comment: I updated the answer. If you want the event to fire only when *everything* on the page is done loading, use the `$(window).load()` event.